# Interval topology of the poset of all coverings

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, posets

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset. The *interval topology* $\tau_i(P)$ on $P$ is generated by
$$\{P\setminus\downarrow x : x\in P\} \cup \{P\setminus\uparrow x : x\in P\},$$
where $\downarrow x = \{y\in P: y\leq x\}$ and $\uparrow x = \{y\in P: y\geq x\}$.

Now let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set. We say that $U\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is a *proper covering* if

- $\bigcup U = X$, and
- for $a\neq b\in U$ we have $a\not\subseteq b$.

Let $\text{Cov}(X)$ denote the collection of all (proper) coverings of $X$. For $A, B\in \text{Cov}(X)$ we set $A\leq B$ if $A$ refines $B$, that is for all $a\in A$ there is $b\in B$ such that $a\subseteq b$. (The reason we only consider proper coverings, and not all coverings, is that the refinement relation is not anti-symmetric for all coverings.)

Is the interval topology $\tau_i(\text{Cov}(X))$ Hausdorff for infinite sets $X$?